# For disks that need to be stored for an unknown future use, leave no partition map? or one empty partition (what format?)?

Tags: hard-drive

I have 5 (hdd / ssd) that all have SATA interfaces ranging in size from 320gb to 1tb. They will have their contents deleted and then put in storage for some unknown use on either Windows / Apple / Linux in a maybe few months.

Using *Ubuntu* **fdisk** [d] command, I will delete the partition tables and verify there's no data or /boot/efi partition.

But, before removal, is it standard to then create 1 partition on each disk? Perhaps the entire size of the disk and formatted "Linux filesystem"? "W95 FAT32"?

I'm guessing that I can make a used disk look "brand new" by deleting all the partitions with **fdisk**, and that's it? And thus this is the best "format" to store disks that are ready to be re-used for any purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This article below discusses pros and cons of unpowered HDD and SSD storage.

[Hard Drive storage](https://eshop.macsales.com/blog/43702-we-bet-you-didnt-know-that-your-hdds-or-ssds-may-need-exercise-too/)

> Hard Drive Failure Mechanisms The length of time your data will be
> retained on a hard drive in storage, one that isn’t powered and kept
> in a controlled environment, is based on four primary factors:
>
> Magnetic Field Deterioration:
>
> Magnetic Field Corruption
>
> Environmental Conditions:
>
> Mechanical Failure:
>
> Under those ideal conditions, hard drives are predicted to be able to
> retain their data for 9 to 20 years. The long range is due to the
> different architectures used in the manufacturing of modern hard
> drives.

I would look to the lower end and even suggest not storing a drive longer that 5 years not powered.

Some cheaper consumer drives can die for stuck motor or heads fairly quickly.

I do not think it matters a lot whether the stored drives have partitions or not.